# C++ function with a generic and optional class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I define this function with a generic (and optional) class object:

```
template <class OptionalClass = void>
double galg(std::function<double(std::vector<double>, OptionalClass)> func, std::vector<double>& parameters, OptionalClass extrainfo);
```

And use it as:

```
double res = galg(fun, par, extra);
```

Where:

```
std::vector<double> par;
c_myclass extra;
double fun(std::vector<double> parameters, c_myclass extrainfo);
```

However I keep getting this error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘galg(double (&)(std::vector<double>, c_myclass), std::vector<double>&, c_myclass&)’
   err = galg(fun, par, extra);
                                                                                                   ^
In file included from ... note: candidate: ‘template<class OptionalClass> double galg(std::function<double(std::vector<double>, OptionalClass)>, std::vector<double>&, OptionalClass)’

 double galg(
        ^~~~~~~~~~~
... note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
... note:   mismatched types ‘std::function<double(std::vector<double>, OptionalClass)>’ and ‘double (*)(std::vector<double>, c_myclass)’
   err = galg(fun, par, extra);
```

Why? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], the error message is not coming from the line you show here

Comment: The `= void` won't help anything, because `void` is not a valid function parameter type.  I'd probably write a second overload which calls this one by wrapping its functor in a lambda and using a `std::nullptr_t` or `std::monostate` or similar for the third argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

template argument deduction don't perform implicit conversions.

The issue here is that you passing a pointer to function to `fun` which is `double (*) (std::vector<double>, c_myclass)` and the function parameter is expecting `std::function<double(std::vector<double>, OptionalClass)>`, and is using a template parameter that at that moment is unknown.

Your options are:

- provide the explicit template argument: `galg<c_myclass>(fun, par, extra)`
- trigger the implicit conversion before calling `galg`:

  ```
  galg(std::function(f), par, extra)
  ```

and the third courtesy of @aschepler is to disallow the deduction on the first parameter and let the third deduce `OptionalClass`:

```
template <class T> struct identity {using type = T;};
template <class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template <class OptionalClass>
double galg(identity_t<std::function<double(std::vector<double>,OptionalClass)>> func, std::vector<double>& params, OptionalClass extra);

galg(fun, par, extra);
```

Comment: or just `galg(std::function(f), par, extra)` in one line :)

Comment: Or put the first parameter in a non-deduced context: `template <class OptionalClass> galg(identity_t<std::function<double(std::vector<double>,OptionalClass)>> func, std::vector<double>& params, OptionalClass extra);`

Comment: It looks much better. However, *cmake* keeps returning now: `undefined reference to double galg<c_myclass>(std::function<double (std::vector<double>, c_myclass)>, std::vector<double>&, c_myclass)`

Comment: @Medicalphysicist pretty sure link error, you have to define the functions not just declare them.